# Algorithm for mapping network devices

Tags: algorithm, networking, diagram

Does anyone know a good method for mapping devices on a network?

I am looking for something that can establish the connection layout between devices to build a visual network diagram.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't an algorithm, but rather a protocol (or protocols) for discovering neighbors. If your switches/devices have [Link Layer Discovery Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_Layer_Discovery_Protocol) (LLDP) enabled, you can use that to determine a network of physical connections.

Note that older Cisco switches might not have LLDP, but will have CDP, a proprietary implementation of discovery. Same goes for Nortel and Extreme switches which also have their proprietary protocols. But LLDP is now the standard ([802.1AB](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee802/download/802.1AB-2005.pdf)) that should be used for discovery.

You can also see on the Wikipedia page that there are implementations of LLDP (and other proprietary protocols) for Linux/Windows/Mac. Also, VMware ESX implements CDP.